# PowerPoint file shows more row height of a table than calculated height applied from code using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I am using Apache POI 5.2.1 library to create a PowerPoint file.
If height is set using API XSLFTableRow.setHeight() it doesn't get properly set on the PowerPoint.
If the file is opened, we can see the row's height in layout tab which is different.
The height seen in PowerPoint file in layout tab is more than what was applied through code.

Example, I have applied row height as 26 points through code. But height seen in layout tab of PowerPoint file is 0.45" i.e. 32.4 points.

Has anyone faced such issue where applied height is more?

If there are many columns, text gets wrapped and the table overflows in slide. When checked the row height is more in PowerPoint file than the calculated value.

The applied row height from code should be same as in row height in PowerPoint's layout tab. Therefore the table shouldn't overflow from slide.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerPoint the table row height cannot be smaller than the text row height needed. Default font size is 18pt. So default text row height is 18pt plus ascender plus descender plus top margin plus bottom margin and that is greater than 26pt. So PowerPoint renders the table row greater to fit the font size.

The following example shows that. The middle table row will be exactly 26pt height as its used font size is only 12pt.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.TableCell.BorderEdge;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXTable {
    
 static void setAllCellBorders(XSLFTableCell cell, Color color) {
  cell.setBorderColor(BorderEdge.top, color);
  cell.setBorderColor(BorderEdge.right, color);
  cell.setBorderColor(BorderEdge.bottom, color);
  cell.setBorderColor(BorderEdge.left, color);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  
  XSLFTable tbl;
  XSLFTableRow row;
  XSLFTableCell cell;  
  
  String[][] data = {
   {"R1C1", "R1C2", "R1C3"},
   {"R2C1", "R2C2", "R2C3"},
   {"R3C1", "R3C2", "R3C3"}
  };
  
  tbl = slide.createTable(data.length, data[0].length);
  tbl.setAnchor(new Rectangle(new Point(100, 100)));

  for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
   //tbl.setRowHeight(r, 26d);
   row = tbl.getRows().get(r);
   row.setHeight(26d);
   String[] dataRow = data[r];
   for (int c = 0; c < dataRow.length; c++) {
    tbl.setColumnWidth(c, 120d);
    String value = dataRow[c];
    cell = tbl.getCell(r, c);
    setAllCellBorders(cell, Color.BLACK);
    cell.setText(value);
    if (r == 1) {
     for (XSLFTextParagraph par : cell.getTextParagraphs()) {
      for (XSLFTextRun run : par.getTextRuns()) {
       run.setFontSize(12d);
      }      
     }
    }
   }
  }

  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXTable.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }
}
```